# Python requests - Persistent sessions and HTML sessionStorage

Tags: python, python-requests

I've been using Python [requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) package and the [locustio](http://locust.io/) package to perform some web performance testing. Unfortunately I am running into a problem with a web application that requires a signature value to be submitted for all subsequent page requests after login.

The signature value is held in Session Storage after login, is there any method within requests that will allow me to retrieve this value from a persistent session?

I have tried using `requests.Session.cookies` but this does not appear to provide the functionality I require.

Apologies if this question format is unacceptable.

ADDITIONAL:

Vikas,

after logging into the web application a value is stored within Session Storage called `app.signature` the value is a hexidecimal string that is updated every 2 secs. I need to extract the current value in order for further interaction with the web-app to be authorised.

Currently my code spawns a session, navigates to the login page and posts the relevant login payload. It is after this point that I need to be able to retrieve the `app.signature` value from local storage.

```
s = requests.Session()
s.get(host + '/login')

payload = "grant_type=password&username=test@testing.co.uk&password=oPxXRvzXEFEeyX5T2gbIwvVS9jibF6VG7ExjBn5r9owKrfChmiboV12R3uJhb6w4a0GRdho_QpUAVr4yrHtbAvhjUnvYFr1cni7qhUER6hh6-W1KUgtInbGpA6FVLiRijZ_ex-oXz5LVM2yHBONYDbU_5sgxIXl5buCGlW_3LQRV56mduEvwF516M13-I8bB_dkGY_WwvK_cVwzZ9TMVdde9n4_qt9zpIkt0ZcWCyDGYsTfYBcTaQjXbPgbOJNUG"

s.post(host + "/token", data=payload)
```

After this point I have tried using `s.cookies` but this doesn't appear to access anything held within HTML5 session storage.

Comment: Could you please provide more information on 'Session Storage' that is saved and needs to be retrieved. Also, are you using `requests` object or `session` object?

Comment: Vikas: I have updated my original post with some further information. Let me know if there is anything else I can do to clarify further.